# Execution of request failed while querying via Google calendar API

Tags: c#, windows, google-calendar-api

I'm using Visual C# Express 2010 under Windows 7. I have been using this code for querying my Google calendars (there are 4 of them) for the last 3 years without any problems. However, yesterday (17/11/14) the code stopped working. Here is the code:

```
try
{
    //fill up combobox with all calendars
    CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
    myService.setUserCredentials(email, password);
    CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
    query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
    CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed) myService.Query(query); //code crashes
}
catch (GDataRequestException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\r\nCould not read from Google Calendar");
}
```

The code crashes when the query is made with this error message:

> Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full

Does anyone have any idea why the code suddenly has stopped working when the same code was working fine the previous day?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I found the problem.  Google API v2 was deprecated on 17/11/14 and replaced with v3. All change!

Comment: BTW thanks for editing my question, Yuri.  I'll make sure to get it right next time.

Comment: Same here, stopped working 2 days ago.
Hey, Brian, thanks for commenting that V2 is deprecated.
Is v3 working fine?

Comment: Hi
I am also facing the similar problem but I am already V3. If you have made changes to your code, can you please post them here?